# Why the response is good in Response but she isn't inject in State of Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch, state, payload

Hello I am starting and I come to ask my first question.

Indeed, I want to inject information into the State of Redux.

```
export const GET_USER = "GET_USER";

export const getUser = () => {
    const newVar = async (dispatch) => {
        await fetch (${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/user/me, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token,
                'User': localStorage.user,
            },
            credentials: "same-origin",
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log( 'user get  :'+response)
                dispatch({type:GET_USER, payload: response})
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    };
    return newVar
}
```

I get the following result:

> in the Response of my console:

```
XHRGEThttp://localhost:8000/api/user/me
[HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 7ms]


lastname    Ceasar
firstname   Jules
email   "jc@mail.com"
cellphone   0505050505
id  "57e925c0-5619-492c-8640-a8102a40bcbf"
```

> in the State of Redux (i don't have data):

```
userReducer(pin): {}
```

> Console.log :

```
console.log ('user get:' + response) => user get: [object Response]

console.log (response) => does not appear
```

I search the solution for give data one Redux State.
Thanks for the trail if you have one for me :)

Good day

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your api returns json then according to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) you have to use `response.json()` on the response. So it should be: `fetch().then(respose=>response.json()).then(result=>dispatch...)`

The code in your reducer may be wrong as well but can only guess because that part is missing in your question.